# this command is not available unless the connection is created with admin-commands enabled

Tags: redis, booksleeve

When trying to run the following in Redis using booksleeve.

```
using (var conn = new RedisConnection(server, port, -1, password))
{
    var result = conn.Server.FlushDb(0);
    result.Wait();
}
```

I get an error saying:

> This command is not available unless the connection is created with
>   admin-commands enabled"

I am not sure how do i execute commands as admin? Do I need to create an a/c in db with admin access and login with that?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Basically, the dangerous commands that you don't need in routine operations, but which can cause lots of problems if used inappropriately (i.e. the equivalent of `drop database` in tsql, since your example is `FlushDb`) are protected by a "yes, I meant to do that..." flag:

```
using (var conn = new RedisConnection(server, port, -1, password,
          allowAdmin: true)) <==== here
```

I will improve the error message to make this very clear and explicit.

Comment: Is there a list of which commands require `allowAdmin`? From searching the source code, it appears to just be flushing and changing which servers are masters.

Answer (score 80):

Updated answer for [StackExchange.Redis](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis):

```
var conn = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost,allowAdmin=true");
```

Note also that the object created here should be created once per application and shared as a global singleton, per [Marc](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/master/Docs/Basics.md):

> Because the ConnectionMultiplexer does a lot, it is designed to be
>   shared and reused between callers. You should not create a
>   ConnectionMultiplexer per operation. It is fully thread-safe and ready
>   for this usage.

Answer (score 9):

You can also set this in C# when you're creating your multiplexer - set `AllowAdmin` = true

```
    private ConnectionMultiplexer GetConnectionMultiplexer()
    {
        var options = ConfigurationOptions.Parse("localhost:6379");
        options.ConnectRetry = 5;
        options.AllowAdmin = true;
        return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(options);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

For those who like me faced the error:

> StackExchange.Redis.RedisCommandException: This operation is not
> available unless admin mode is enabled: ROLE

after upgrading StackExchange.Redis to version 2.2.4 with Sentinel connection: it's a [known bug](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1628), the workaround was either to downgrade the client back or to add `allowAdmin=true` to the connection string and wait for the fix.

**Starting from 2.2.50 public release the issue is fixed.**

Comment: Downgrading to 2.1.58 helped.